# json_encode() array in while loop for mySQL for calendar

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, json, loops

I do not know what I am doing when it comes to JSON. So this may be a stupid question and I may be trying to do it a weird way. Any help would be great.

I have this Jquery Calendar I am trying to put on my website. It allows for json_encode for dates. Here is the example they gave.

```
    $year = date('Y');
$month = date('m');

echo json_encode(array(

    array(
        'id' => 111,
        'title' => "Event1",
        'start' => "$year-$month-10",
        'url' => "http://yahoo.com/"
    ),

    array(
        'id' => 222,
        'title' => "Event2",
        'start' => "$year-$month-20",
        'end' => "$year-$month-22",
        'url' => "http://yahoo.com/"
    )

));
```

I want to use an existing mySQL database to populate the calendar. Here is what I have so far. It isn't working and I don't think I am being intelligent with this.

```
$dataSQL ="select *
            FROM events
        ";

$dataResult = mysqli_query($dataBase, $dataSQL);

$encode = array();

$p=0;
    while($allRow = mysqli_fetch_array($dataResult))
        {
            $new = array(
                        'id' => "$allRow['id']",
                        'title' => "$allRow['title']",
                        'start' => "$allRow['date']",
                        'url' => "$allRow['url']"
                    );
            array_splice($encode, ($p), 0, $new);

            $p++;
        }


echo json_encode($encode);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Shouldn't $dataSQL variable come first as an argument to mysqli_query()?

Comment: not for procedural style like this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're just having problems with your array structure, you've gone a bit complex. You can build an array like this:

```php
$encode = array();

while($allRow = mysqli_fetch_array($dataResult))
       {
            $new = array(
                        'id' => $allRow['id'],
                        'title' => $allRow['title'],
                        'start' => $allRow['date'],
                        'url' => $allRow['url']
                    );
            $encode[] = $new;

        }

echo json_encode($encode);
```