# PHP JSON result multiple empty

Tags: php, mysql, json

I developed an android application with Mysql database. I would like the result of my sql query is displayed in a JSON variable in a table. If I use a single column of my TableA "country" ---> "id_country" or "name_en_country" it works but if I want to display more columns ---> "id_country" AND "name_en_country" AND more .. ... The result Requet php send me a blank page. Could you help me please thank you!

```
<?php

// Create Database connection
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "whenmeeat");
if (!$mysqli) {
    printf("Échec de la connexion : %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Replace * in the query with the column names.
$result = $mysqli->query("select id_country, name_en_country, name_fr_country from country", MYSQLI_USE_RESULT);

// Create an array
$json_response["country"] = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    $row_array['id_country'] = $row['id_country'];
    $row_array['name_en_country'] = $row['name_en_country'];

    // push the values in the array
    array_push($json_response["country"],$row_array);
}
echo json_encode($json_response["country"]);

// Close the database connection
$mysqli->close();

?>
```

Comment: Blank page normally means you haven't configured PHP to display error messages. You need to fix that first, rather than trying to guess all the time.

Comment: If I have php error, I have an error page that appears. I already try.

Comment: Then it's possibly that you're simply getting `NULL`. You can verify that with `var_dump(json_encode(...))` and (if that's the case) you can see the error with [json_last_error()](http://php.net/json_last_error). I have the impression that you aren't feeding JSON functions with proper UTF-8.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example set here [json_encode() array in while loop for mySQL for calendar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11236423/json-encode-array-in-while-loop-for-mysql-for-calendar) your code should alter like this:

```
<?php
// Create Database connection
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "whenmeeat");
if (!$mysqli) {
    printf("Échec de la connexion : %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
}

// Replace * in the query with the column names.
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT `id_country`, `name_en_country`, `name_fr_country` FROM `country`");
$stmt->execute();
$res = $stmt->get_result(); 
// Create an array
$json = array();
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            $country = array(
                        'id_country' => $row['id_country'],
                        'name_en_country' => $row['name_en_country'],
                        'name_fr_country' => $row['name_fr_country']
                    );
            $json[] = $country ;
}
echo json_encode($json);
// Close the database connection
$mysqli->close();
?>
```

Comment: hello I tried your code and have the same result if I put a single column to display it works but if I put more column I have a blank page.

Comment: yes i try. you and a screenshot ? i can if you want

Comment: I think you won't have a problem now.

Comment: Sorry it's not work, same problem. omg i dont understand why, when i delete 2 row "'name_en_country' => $row['name_en_country'],
                        'name_fr_country' => $row['name_fr_country'] " it's work.

Comment: Please check your table settings. In my localhost example i got this results. [{"id_country":2,"name_en_country":"USA","name_fr_country":"USA"},{"id_country":3,"name_en_country":"Greece","name_fr_country":"Grece"}]

Comment: i try display colomns one by one. it's not work for name_fr_country and name_en_country. So i tested my query in phpMyAdmin and my query works.

Comment: Could it be that you mistype those 2 fields in your code?

Comment: i try to make a fake name columns. php error mean :Notice: Undefined index: name_en_FakeName in D:\wamp\www\android_connect\get_countrys.php on line 16. So it's make a good name columns but the result it's blank page. dont understand. it's possible a forget a think but what .....

Comment: if i remplace $json[] by $json my result display a last name table country. So why it's work for one result but not for array ?

Comment: Create a temporary table with no indexes at all, make it have 3 fields `id_country`, `name_en_country`, `name_fr_country` insert some demo values and run the above code. You will not have an issue.